# Is Dependency Injection always the right answer?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, service-locator

I'm currently thinking a lot about dependency injection and it's pro's and con's. Generally speaking there seems to be the consensus that dependency injection is the right choice in most of the cases. I see where it comes handy and how it makes the code more readable. Accordingly I'm trying to create my classes with as much dependency injection as possible, separating the concerns into multiple objects. In 70% of my daily work this is fine. It works and I see the benefits.

However there are the remaining 30% which let me struggle quite a bit. I don't have problems with the concept of dependency injection itself, but with the fact that I think PHP does have some "special properties" that let me have doubts that dependency injection is the right choice.

1. The main point that seems to be THE PRO for using DI instead of, let's say a service-locator is that you have "compile-time errors" instead of "run-time errors". I get that, for languages like Java or C, but there is no such thing as a "compile-time error" in PHP that would not automatically result in a "run-time error". At least I never encountered one.
2. In programs that boot up once, load their source into the memory and stay there as long as they are executed I get why you would want to use DI. It makes sense, you don't have to worry (in general) about how much time the app needs to reach the running state and you should (in general) have enough memory to keep all your code there. So loading all dependencies and keeping them in memory seems to be fine. However, a PHP script, when used in an Apache, NGINX, or some other context will boot up every time a user accesses it. In addition to that we want our app to run as fast as possible, with as less resources as possible to get the most out of the servers hardware. The thing is, if I load the entirety of the library every time, even if I just access a fraction of the code it seems quite wasteful... (I have an example of what I mean below)
3. As stated above I try to use DI as much as possible. But the remaining 30% I still handle using the service-locator pattern because I a.) Just need a dependency under a certain condition or b.) I access a service/helper class that is more or less substitutable with a global function. (See example below)

In that regard, I read a lot about how a.) Helper classes are evil b.) When you use a dependency just once in your class you should split it into a separate class (Which to be honest is a point I don't quite get, because when you use DI you have to create the class anyway so why split it of from the general class?).

I created some dummy code to showcase the 30% where I think (at the point of writing this) a service locator is (in PHP) more sensible than DI.

```php
class RecordHandler {
    // Use a trait to enable access to the getInstanceOf() method,
    // which is a link to the global instance of the service container singleton
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    /**
     * @var EnvService
     */
    protected $envService;

    /**
     * RecordHandler constructor.
     *
     * @param EnvService $envService
     */
    public function __construct(EnvService $envService) {
        $this->envService = $envService;
    }

    // ... Other methods...

    public function filterRecords(array $records): array {
        // Using the normal DI object...
        if($this->envService->isStaging()){
            // Do something different ...
            return [];
        }

        foreach($records as $recordId => $record){
            // This can happen in 10% of the times...
            // I don't know here if the database is already connected. 
            // The factory registered in the container will initialize the connection when the object is created...
            if(empty($record)){
                $record = $this->getInstanceOf(DbService::class)->query("SELECT * FROM `stored_record_table WHERE id = ?", [$recordId]);
            }

            // This can happen, but it does not happen in 50% of the cases...
            if(!empty($record["xmlField"])){
                $record["xmlField"] = $this->getInstanceOf(XmlService::class)->handleXml($record["xmlField"]);
            }

            // Creating a class instance based on the record's value...
            if(!empty($record["classField"]) && class_exists($record["classField"]) && 
                in_array(HandlerInterface::class, class_implements($record["classField"]))) {
                $i = $this->getInstanceOf($record["classField"]);
                $i->handle($record);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that EnvService and DbService are marked as "Singleton" inside the used service container. Meaning once they are created the container will return the same instance over and over again.

I'm really curious to see if there are better solutions to this as I tested around with multiple solutions and doing it like this saves like 30-50% of execution time with a fluctuation based on what kinds of records are handled.

Also I'm aware of the downsides like hiding dependencies away and such. To prevent that issue I tried to create "context objects" which are basically hardcoded DI containers, but they don't seem to be the option either.

Lastly I tried to use "lazy loading" to avoid said issues, but PHP-DI for example explicitly says in it's documentation that you should not create lazy loading proxies for more than 3-4 classes, which seems not that helpful.

Comment: `Is Dependency Injection always the right answer in PHP?` "nothing" is "always".

Comment: That was maybe a bit of a joke, but: sometime DI is very pleasant; changing stuff around and not need to change it at 500 different places. That's cool. But sometimes you just need a specific component within one of your services/codefile/classes/etc. Nothing is wrong with just instantiating it.

Comment: Even though it's not written for PHP, you might find the book [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://manning.com/seemann2) (that I coauthored) valuable, as it discusses many of the issues you are dealing with, such as downsides of Service Locator, how to handle performance issues, the general design principles behind it, and when to apply DI and when *not* to apply DI. There are just a few chapters that are specific to .NET (7, 13, 14, and 15) that can be easily skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No pattern is always the answer**; It's important to make informed, pragmatic architecture decisions when these can't be deferred.

You are right stating that in the case of PHP, since the whole object graph has to be instantiated on each request, DI might incur in a performance penalty.

However, **dependency injection is clearly not about performance**. Its a way to implement inversion of control, and ultimately towards a modular design, separation of concerns, reusability and **testability**. These benefits greatly exceed the "compile-time" error catching ability.

In the early stages of a software project, it is very difficult and risky to predict whether it is going to be simple enough (your 30%) to forego all these benefits and go for an interconnected design instead of a modular one, where the moving parts are tightly coupled, just in name or performance.